# Not able to list Bigquery projects from Data Studio Connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

From Data Studio, I am not able to list any Big Query projects. Not even Public projects. I have access to Big Query Tables and projects, but once I log in through Data Studio and try to add a data source, it's showing all blank, including custom queries, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same situation and I hope this helps someone else with this confusion. I'm assuming that this could be the solution to this question too. (Do let me know)

When you are trying to add a BigQuery connection to Data Studio, you need to have a Google Project because BigQuery is a paid service. The querying in BigQuery incurs a cost. A project with billing enabled, is not a must for you to load the Datasets in the above screenshot.

Follow these steps to get this issue fixed.

1. **Check the email address** you have used to connect to Data Studio. You can click on the avatar on the top right corner. (If this is wrong, simply switch to the correct email.)
2. **Check whether Google Cloud Console is enabled** for the above-selected email.
3. **Check whether you have a project** in the Cloud Console. Make sure there is a project to be used when creating a BigQuery connection from Data Studio.

With this, your view should show the projects linked with your Google Cloud Console email address.
[image]

If the above doesn't work..

- Do a refresh of the page and see
- If not, create a support ticket or Ask the [Data Studio Community](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/new).